# PTIJ: If Bernie Sanders had been elected, would Eruvei Chatzeiros have become unnecessary?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The way Eruvei Chatzeiros works is by making it like everyone who participated owns a part of the others' property.

Since [Bernie Sanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Sanders) ran on a [communist platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Bernie_Sanders), had he won, everyone's property would have been owned by everyone, anyway. In that scenario, would Eruvei Chatzeiros have been moot?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Moreover, as he would be the head of the military, we wouldn't have to rent anything from the police department.

Comment: That’s not how socialism works. OUR property would belong to EVERYONE. Bernie’s property would remain his. I think it’s similar to the Torah concept of how the ashes that purifies the impure contaminates the one who uses the ashes to purify the contaminated.  Or something like that

Comment: According to your link, Sanders didn't advocate for communal ownership or abolishing profit, so attributing that position to him in this question doesn't seem right.  You could ask about a socialist government in the abstract as it applies to this halacha.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That’s supposed to be part of the joke. Oh well.

Comment: Oh, I (obviously) didn't get that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, under a Communist government, *Eruvei Chatzierot* would be taken care of as a matter of course by the People.

As described in the *Halachipedia* article on ["Introduction to the Modern Eruv"](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Introduction_to_the_Modern_Eruv#Introduction_to_the_modern_day_eruv:), there are three elements necessary to give city streets the technical definition of "private domain," such that there's no problem with carrying in them on Shabbat:

1. Physical enclosure of the area in question.
2. Joint partnership between the people living there.
3. Deed of rental of the area from the local government.

The Communist regime provides for all three of these requirements, as of course it must, based on the principle of ["To each according to his needs."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_each_according_to_his_ability,_to_each_according_to_his_needs) And of course, it's [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruv#Coping_without_an_eruv) for Jews to live in a place where they can't carry things around outside on Shabbat. Taking these requirements in the [traditional](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.24?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.24.24.1&lang2=bi) [order](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUC7TK2V3wQ):

**Three**. Under Communism, the People have authority over all of the streets, so there's no need to get any special deeds from Western Imperial constructs like local government.

**Two**. As the question surmises, all property is in common anyway, so partnership in all relevant property is a given.

**One**. Ah, but what about physical enclosure of the area? This is accomplished in two ways:

- Everyone who lives in the Communist regime must become a member of the Communist Party and therefore join Comrade Sanders on the Communist Party Platform. The Party Platform is the most elevated expression of human political thought in history and therefore must be at least the [requisite](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hotzah#Definition_of_the_4_domains) 10 *tefachim* tall to make everyone on it part of the same *reshut hayachid*.
- To ensure that all of the people under its protection are oriented toward the best interests of the People, the Communist government puts up a series of closed-circuit cameras all around each city, and especially around the borders thereof. The wires connecting these cameras can double conveniently as the [*tzurot hapetach*](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Introduction_to_the_Modern_Eruv#Explanations_of_the_tzurat_ha-petah_enclosure) necessary to form a modern Eruv. And thus, we can re-establish fulfillment of the [age-old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_reversal) proverb:

  > *In capitalist America, [you check Eruv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruv#Checking_the_eruv).
  >
  >   In Soviet Russia, Eruv checks you!*

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the question is the best answer.

Here's a slightly edited quote:

> Since Bernie Sanders ran on a communist platform, had he won, everyone's property would have been owned by everyone, anyway. In that scenario, Eruvei Chatzeiros would have been moot.